# Session timeout event in magento

Tags: php, magento

I wanted to do some custom functionality upon user logout, so I hooked to the customer logout event, and added an observer to it.

Here's the configuration in config.xml

```
<customer_logout>
  <observers>
    <cwmyaccount>
      <type>singleton</type>
      <class>KrtMalta_Myaccount_Model_Observer</class>
      <method>setRegularCustomer</method>
    </cwmyaccount>
  </observers>
</customer_logout>
```

However I'd like the execute my custom functionality even on session-timeout. I've looked up google and Magento files with pretty much no success. Is it possible to hook to session-timeout somehow?

Answer (score 2):

Sessions are cleaned up automatically by PHP when a session is started and there is currently no way to hook into this process unless you write your own [custom session handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.customhandler.php).

If you write your own handler, then PHP will call your `gc` method giving you control over the old session data that gets destroyed.  Keep in mind that this happens at the start of the request (when session_start() is called) so you would want whatever processing you do to happen very quickly as not to delay the request being processed.