# PHP Do something when session gets expired

Tags: php

So let's say user did something on my website, for example uploaded some images or whatever, and he left without logging out and never came back or let's say he did come back after few months.

So my question would be, is there some kind of way for example to delete his uploaded files after session have expired, let's say after 30 mins (keep in mind that user never reloaded page), so that would need to run entirely on server side without user interfering at all.

**EDIT** Thank you all for your wonderful answers, it gave me quite a few great ideas, i wish i could accept all of your answers :)

Comment: One way is to enforce user registration, but I'd like to see what answers would people come up with.

Comment: Browse [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11216529/session-timeout-event-in-magento) also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be to call

```
  $thePath = session_save_path();
```

and iterate over all saved session file, unserialze each and check them for the specified timeout property.

Unfortunately, you need to **scan the whole directory** to find all session files, which are older than a defined period of time. You'd use `start()` to figure out the age of a session file.

On a well-maintained server, each virtual host should have a separate directory for its session data. A not-so-well-maintained might store all sessions in a unified shared directory. Therefore, ensure that you don't read or delete other virtual hosts' session data.

### Better Approach using a database

Therefore I propose to **save session data to your application's backend database**. Using SQL, it would be trivial to find all outdated session files.

The documentation for `session_set_save_handler()` provides a sample, which [explains this whole process](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) quite nicely based on objects.

Answer (score 6):

Good question! My first idea was to use a database based solution. If you don't already, you'd keep track of all active sessions in a table `sessions` which contains, among other things you may need, the `session_id` and the `last_visited_time`. This entry would be updated every time a user visits your site:

```
UPDATE sessions WHERE session_id = "<current session id>" SET last_visited_time = NOW()
```

The second part of the mechanism would be a cronjob that scans the the `sessions` table for sessions whose `last_visisted_time` hasn't been updated lately (in whatever time interval you'd like) and deletes the files for that session.

Answer (score 1):

I like all the answers above, but a different solution would be to name the uploaded files in a way that you know they are "temporary", for example prepending their name with a timestamp. This way, a periodic process would clean any such files, unless your program decides that they should be kept after all, renaming them accordingly.

Comment: This would work if his requirement was to delete temporary files after a certain time, however the OP wants to perform a certain action (deleting some files) after a users session expires, which might be after 30 minutes, but might very well be after several hours. Therefore, your approach might delete files even before a user session has expired. You could then say "I  clean files that have been created one week ago" making almost sure that the user session has expired by then, but that would unnecessarily increase your disk usage 99% of the time (session ~=  30 minutes)

Comment: sure, but the poster said "for example", so I guess that non-session related solutions are not out of the question